# SNMP: not able to query for MAC address

Tags: linux, ubuntu, snmp

I need to query the MAC address of Ubuntu terminals. I remember that a few years ago I've used the OID .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.2 (IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress.2) to query OpenSUSE terminals.

This OID doesn't work with Ubuntu:

```
$ snmpget -v 2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.2
IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress.2 = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

nor:

```
$ snmpget -v 2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6
IF-MIB::ifPhysAddress = No Such Object available on this agent at this OID
```

It seems that all network interfaces are not available at all:

```
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.2
IF-MIB::interfaces = No more variables left in this MIB View (It is past the end of the MIB tree)
```

while if I do an snmpwalk starting from .1.3.6.1.2.1 (SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2) I get a few results.

Why? Is there something that I need to enable to get the MAC address?

I've checked and ifPhysAddress is defined in /usr/share/mibs/ietf/IF-MIB and MIBS seems correctly configured:

```
$ net-snmp-config --default-mibs | grep IF-MIB
:HOST-RESOURCES-MIB:HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES:UCD-DLMOD-MIB:UCD-DISKIO-MIB:LM-SENSORS-MIB:IP-MIB:IF-MIB:TCP-MIB:UDP-MIB:SNMPv2-MIB:RFC1213-MIB:NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB:DISMAN-EVENT-MIB:DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB:UCD-SNMP-MIB:UCD-DEMO-MIB:SNMP-TARGET-MIB:NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB:SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB:SNMP-MPD-MIB:SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB:SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB:SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB:IPV6-ICMP-MIB:IPV6-MIB:IPV6-TCP-MIB:IPV6-UDP-MIB:IP-FORWARD-MIB:NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB:SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB:SNMPv2-TM:NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB
```

The packages I've installed are:

```
ii  libsnmp-base          4.4.1~dfsg-12ubuntu7               SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) MIBs and documen
ii  libsnmp15             5.4.1~dfsg-12ubuntu7               SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) library
ii  snmp                  5.4.1~dfsg-12ubuntu7               SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) applications
ii  snmpd                 5.4.1~dfsg-12ubuntu7               SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol) agents
```

#### Update:

Below there's the snmpd.conf of the target machines:

```
com2sec paranoid  default         public
group MyROSystem v1        paranoid
group MyROSystem v2c       paranoid
group MyROSystem usm       paranoid
group MyROGroup v1         readonly
group MyROGroup v2c        readonly
group MyROGroup usm        readonly
group MyRWGroup v1         readwrite
group MyRWGroup v2c        readwrite
group MyRWGroup usm        readwrite
view all    included  .1                               80
view system included  .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system
access MyROSystem ""     any       noauth    exact  system none   none
access MyROGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  all    none   none
access MyRWGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  all    all    none
syslocation Unknown (configure /etc/snmp/snmpd.local.conf)
syscontact Root <root@localhost> (configure /etc/snmp/snmpd.local.conf)
```

Comment: Do you have access to this part of the tree on the receiving side?  Can you post the snmpd.conf from one of the servers (minus comments and blank lines)

Comment: @Paul I've just updated the question with the config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `public` community string maps to the `paranoid` group, which maps to the `MyROSystem access`, which allows visibility of the `system` view.  Can you change:

```
com2sec paranoid  default         public
```

to read

```
com2sec readonly  default         public
```

This will map it to `readonly` and give it the whole tree.